# Max tensor (not element) in an n-dimensional tensor

Tags: tensorflow, max, tensor

I am finding it impossible to get the max tensor in an n-dimensional array, even by summing the tensors and using gather or gather_nd.

By max tensor I mean the set of weights with the highest sum.

I have a tensor of shape (-1, 4, 30, 256) where 256 is the weights.

I need to get the maximum set of weights for each (-1, 0, 30), (-1, 1, 30), (-1, 2, 30) and (-1, 3, 30), so under each tensor in the 2nd dimension.

This would ideally result in a (-1, 4, 256) tensor.

reduce_max and any other max function will only return the maximum element values within the last dimension, not the maximum tensor (which is the set of weights with the highest sum) in the dimension itself. I have tried:

```
p1 = tf.reduce_sum(tensor, axis=3) # (-1, 4, 30)
p2 = tf.argmax(p1, 2) # (-1, 4)
```

Which gives the appropriate index values for the 3rd dimension:

```
[[0, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 0],
 ...
```

But running tf.gather or tf.gather_nd on the above does not work, even when splitting my data beforehand and using different axes.

Further, I can get the appropriated indexes if I use gather_nd by hand, eg:

```
tf.gather_nd(out5, [[0,0,0], [0,1,2], [0,2,2], [0,3,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,2], [1,2,2], [1,3,1]])
```

But as we are using a tensorflow variable of an unknown first dimension, I cannot build these indexes.

I have searched through related workarounds and found nothing applicable.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this? Thanks!

edit for clarification:

The maximum tensor of weights would be the set of weights with the highest sum:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2]] would be [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What do you mean by maximum tensor? Do you mean the tensor with the maximum single entry, or the tensor with the maximum length, or something else?

Comment: The set of weights (tensor) which has the highest summed value, eg weights [[ 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 2]] would be [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using map_fn:

I reshaped my tensor to (-1, 120, 256)

```
tfr = tf.reshape(sometensor, ((-1, 120, 256)))
def func(slice):
    f1 = tf.reduce_sum(slice, axis=1)
    f2 = tf.argmax(f1)
    return(slice[f2])
bla = tf.map_fn(func, tfr)
```

Which returns (-1,256) with the greatested summed vector (highest set of weights).

Basically, map_fn will iterate along the 2nd to last axis, so it slices a chunk of (120,256) to func repeatedly (how ever many entries are on the first axis). It then returns the appropriate (1,256) chunk by chunk which, voila, gives the answer.